# How would I remove a element from an array after it's been answered?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

So I'm developing a quiz app for iOS and have my code set up to where I have an array that contains questions and a function that displays a random question from that array of questions. How could I configure code to make sure after a question has been asked it's removed from the array until all the other questions from the array have been answered or until a subsequent question from the array is answered wrong and resets the whole quiz, then adding back all the answered questions back to the array once it is reset? How would I configure code to see if the random question has been answered or not by the user? Basically once a question is asked I don't want it asked again until all other questions have been asked first.

Here is my code (I want the func randomQuestion to remove the question from the array after it is asked once):

```
@IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel! 

let questions = [//array of questions inside these brackets]

//random question generation function
func randomQuestion() {
    index = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(questions.count)))
    questionLabel.text = questions[index]
```

Comment: what have you tried? can show some part of the code you are currently using and we can start from there

Comment: I hope the questions on your quiz are easier to understand or at least shorter than the first in this post :P

Comment: Generate your array of questions: create a shuffled mutable copy of it (this will be randomization part) and start picking and removing questions one by one from end of the array (like from a stack data object). If the user answers a question wrong: throw away the shuffled mutable array and re-shuffle the original full questions array: repeat until a shuffled array become empty, in which case the user successfully answered all questions (in a random sequence).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly if answer is correct then find index of that particular question in array and add that array object to another dummy array and remove it from questions array, and if he answered wrongly then add that dummy array objects to questions array back,

```
var arrQuestions = [String]()
var arrAnsweredQuestions = [String]()
if(answerCorrect) {
  let index = arrQuestions.index(of: question)
  arrQuestions.remove(at: index)
  arrAnsweredQuestions.append(question)
} else {
 for question in arrAnsweredQuestions {
    arrQuestions.append(question)
 }
 arrAnsweredQuestions.removeAll()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you pull a question from the array in order to ask it to the user, you store its **index** in some variable.

If the user answers the question correctly, remove the element at that index, and move on. Because removing the element at index n causes the subsequent elements to fall down one position, you shold proceed again with element at index n (formerly at n+1), unless that is past the array's bounds in which case you should go back to index 0 (unless empty, i.e. the user has answered all questions).

If the user answers incorrectly, proceed to the next question (next index, n+1) without removing the failed question from the array, until you reach the end of the array (at which point you should loop back to index 0).

Does it makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Check below code i am having _bidderArray of dictionaries and i want to change bidAmount inside the Dictionary.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[_bidderArray objectAtIndex:_selectedIndex.row] mutableCopy];
[dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", bidAmount ] forKey:@"your_bid"];
[_bidderArray replaceObjectAtIndex:_selectedIndex.row withObject:[dict copy]];
```